# Authentification to app engine endpoint api fails

Tags: ios, google-app-engine, google-oauth, mysql-python

Ok so I'm set up my endpoint api code and my iOS Authentication exactly as mentioned in the google platform docs and yet for some reason I'm not prompted with a login screen when presenting the OAuth2ViewControllerTouch view controller.

My endpoint api looks like this:

```
@endpoints.api(
    name='authed_api_calls',
    version='v1',
    # Only allowed configured Client IDs to access this API.
    allowed_client_ids=ALLOWED_CLIENT_IDS,
    # Only allow auth tokens with the given audience to access this API.
    audiences=[ANDROID_AUDIENCE,WEB_CLIENT_ID],
    # Require auth tokens to have the following scopes to access this API.
    scopes=[endpoints.EMAIL_SCOPE])

class AuthedAPICalls(remote.Service): 

    @endpoints.method(
        message_types.VoidMessage,
        UserData,
        path='get_cur_user',
        http_method='GET',
        name='get_cur_user')
    def get_cur_user_email(self, unused_request):

        ######CODE FOR AUTHORIZING USER####### 
        user = endpoints.get_current_user()

        ret_user = UserData()

        if user is None:

            raise endpoints.UnauthorizedException('Invalid token.')

        else:

            user_name = user.email()

            ret_user.user_email = user_name

        return ret_user
```

My iOS code is as follows. This is where I get the black screen because I'm assuming it's failing to reach the auth url:

```
GTMOAuth2Authentication *auth = [self setupAuth];

GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch *viewController;

viewController = [[GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch alloc] initWithAuthentication:auth
authorizationURL:[NSURL URLWithString:authorizeURL_string]
keychainItemName:kKeychainItemName
delegate:self
finishedSelector:@selector(viewController:finishedWithAuth:error:)];

[[self navigationController] pushViewController:viewController animated:YES];

//commented out because I'm unsure of where it would try and authenticate to.
/*GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch *viewController = [[GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch alloc] initWithScope:OAuthScope
clientID:kMyClientID
clientSecret:kMyClientSecret
keychainItemName:kKeychainItemName
delegate:self
finishedSelector:@selector(viewController:finishedWithAuth:error:)];

[self presentViewController:viewController animated:YES completion:^(void){

//do stuff

}];*/
```

Needless to say the code never arrives at the selector method: viewController:finishedWithAuth:error: either.

Does anyone know why I'm not seeing any result?